# Error 413 al intentar subir fotografia desde celular

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, laravel-6, nginx

Agradezco su atención.

Tengo un formulario en el cual en un input subo una imagen.
Todo funciona normal, desde mi pc cargo una imagen y se guarda exitosamente.
Desde mi celular también cargo alguna imagen guardada en mi galería y bingo!! guarda exitosamente.

Pero no todo es felicidad, porque cuando en vez de buscar en mi galería del celular y opto por tomar una fotografía e intento guardar no se puede... es sumamente extraño. 
Mediante opciones del desarrollador logro obtener un error (413).

bien aqui les muestro el error y el codigo que uso

ERROR

```
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.10 (Ubuntu)</center>
```

VISTA (VUE)

```
  <input type="file" @change="imageLoad" class="form-control-file color-app" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
  <img :src="img" class="img-responsive img-modal" >
```

METHOD IMAGELOAD

```
  imageLoad(e){
                let img = e.target.files[0];
                this.image=img;

                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = (img)=>{
                    this.img =reader.result;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(img);
            },
```

METHOD ADD

```
   add(){
                let data=this;
                let formData=new FormData();
                formData.append('image',this.image);
                axios.post('/articles/add',formData)
                    .then(function (response){
                    data.closeModal();
                })
            },
```

RUTA

```
 Route::post('/articles/add', 'ArticlesController@add');
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function add(Request $request)
    {
        if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

        if ($request->hasfile('image')) {

            $file = $request->file('image');
            $imgName = 'aries' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs('/public/articles', $file, $imgName);
        } else {
            $imgName = "default.jpg";
        }

        Article::create([
            'image' => $imgName,
        ]);

    }
```

BIEN el error para mi es muy extraño y pienso que mi error es usar el formdata, intente también usar otros celulares pero el mismo error.
también pense que el error era solo por usar vue, pero no el error es general.
bueno espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En esta linea se encuentra el error:

```
reader.onloadend = (img)=>{
    //Aquí
    this.img =reader.result;
}
```

Considera que la forma natural de compartir o enviar archivos (y la que creo seria la mas adecuada), es enviar un tipo `File` y no un string **mega largo** en `base64` (esto si lo que quieres es subir el archivo a un servidor), de hecho una forma mas adecuada es simplemente si no puedes obtener un tipo `File` directamente entonces debes crear primero un `Blob` y apartir del Blob crear el `File` y en vez de enviar un string megalargo en `base64` enviar a tu nuevo `File`, por ejemplo aqui en este metodo basta con dejarlo asi para el caso de enviar la imagen al servidor:

```
imageLoad(e){
   let img = e.target.files[0];
   this.image=img;
}
```

Y si deseas mostrar la imagen no puedes usar directamente el `File`, pero puedes usar:

```
URL.createObjectURL();
```

Para no tener que usar `FileReader` de la siguiente manera:

```
imageLoad(e){
   let img = e.target.files[0];

   //La imagen sigue siendo un File y debe seguirlo siendo a la hora
   //de ser enviada.
   this.image=img;
   //Debes usar esto como src de la imagen
   const urlImagen = URL.createObjectURL(this.image);
}
```

Pero para el caso de la camara, creo que si no estoy mal al obtener una imagen de la camara la data es obtenida como un `base64` y no como un tipo `Blob` o un tipo `File`, deberás comprobar esto haciendo un `console.log` de lo que sea que obtengas al usar tu camara.

**Si es un string en base64:**

Deberas leer este articulo que menciona como crear un `Blob` apartir de un `string` en `base64`:

[Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

**Si es un tipo Blob:**

Al ser un tipo `Blob` puedes usar este mismo para crear un tipo `File` de la siguiente manera:

```
//El tercer parametro es opcional. el primero siempre debe recibir un
//Array de Blobs u otros tipos admitidos.
const myFile = new File([myBlob], "Nombre archivo", {type: "image/jpeg"});
```

**Si es un tipo File:**

Solo deberás asignarlo a tu variable y **NO** volver a leerlo como un `base64` ni nada diferente.

```
this.img = myFile;
```

Esto resolverá parcialmente el inconveniente, puesto que hay algo que debo mencionar, y es que si por ejemplo estas usando `xampp`, por defecto `xampp` tiene un limite de subida por `POST` de unos `6` o `5` mb por archivo si no estoy mal, si deseas aumentar esta capacidad deberás dirigirte si no estoy mal a un archivo llamado `php.ini` o `php.conf`, no recuerdo cual de los dos eran, pero de lo que estoy seguro es que debes buscar dos variables dentro de ese archivo que tienen nombres parecidos a:

```
POST_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE
POST_MAX_SIZE
```

Y aumentarle sus numeros.

De lo contrario tu limitación no será el código si no el mismo servidor.

Comment: Nota: es importante no abusar de URL.createObjectURL y ademas recordar que tambien existe URL.revokeObjectURL para destruir la memoria del objeto una vez ya no la uses.

Comment: Gracias por responder, uso laragon en mi pc..con apache..
y debo decir que mi fotografia se sube normal desde mi servidor local 

pero en mi droplet uso nginx y ahi si no puedo hacerlo. debo de considerar lo ultimo que acabas de decir...

Answer (score 0):

bien analice con console.log el tamaño de mi file.

Un screenshot pesaba:
size:4281   575kb aprox.

y una foto pesaba:
size : 4345921   3.4 mb aprox.

era demasiado 
lo que hize fue modificar 2 archivos el nginx.conf y el php.ini:

para esto:

entrar ha nginx.conf con el comando " nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf   " y añadir " client_max_body_size 32M ";
de la siguiente manera:

```
http {
client_max_body_size 32M;  #solo aquí
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
```

luego de haber añadido esto,solo dar ctrl + x  luego "Y" y enter.(esto guardara los cambios)

una vez a fuera poner el comando  " nginx -s reload " (esto recargara nginx.conf)

Ahora solo falta el php.ini

para ingresar, este es el comando "  sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini "

y este es un archivo muy grande asi que buscaras de esta forma:

BUSCAR CON CTRL + W Y DIGITAR  "  post_max "y saldra

" post_max_size = 8M " quiza no te salga 8M quiza otro valor pero agrega el mismo tamaño que le llegaste a poner al nginx.conf  este caso "32M"

así :

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size

post_max_size = 32M  #<-esto te saldra marcado y este modificas

; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =
```

una vez modificado:

dar ctrl + x "Y" y enter (esto guardara el cambio).

y al salir " sudo service php7.4-fpm restart "(esto refrescara el php.ini).

y eso es todo. espero les ayude también pase 2 dias por esto. gracias a los que colaboraron, ayudaron en mi investigación.