# Convertir una imagen PNG, JPEG, JPG a formato WebP al ser subida con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagen, navegador-web

He estado buscando una forma de transformar imágenes con formato PNG, JPEG, JPG al formato WebP mediante JavaScript al ser subida a un formulario en el navegador

Sería el siguiente proceso:
 1. El usuario sube la imagen
 2. El navegador transforma la imagen
 3. Manda el formulario

Mi idea era tomar una "captura de pantalla" a la propia imagen que se sube con jQuery y después guardarla con el formato de WebP, pero buscaba si hay otra forma de conseguirlo directamente con JavaScript

¿Alguien sabe si hay forma de conseguirlo? De verdad agradezco sus ideas

Comment: Desconozco el formato WebP, pero a lo mejor sacas conclusiones con el [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let currentImg = "";
let webpImg = "";
let convertedImg = "";

function handleUploadedFile(ev){

  const file = ev.currentTarget.files[0];
  
  if(currentImg != "" || webpImg != "" || convertedImg != ""){
    URL.revokeObjectURL(currentImg);
    convertedImg = "";
    currentImg = "";
    webpImg = "";
  }
  
  currentImg = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  
  webpImg = new Image();
  
  webpImg.onload = ()=>{
     canvas.width = webpImg.naturalWidth;
     canvas.height = webpImg.naturalHeight;
     ctx.drawImage(webpImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     convertedImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 1.0);
     console.log(convertedImg);
  }
  
  webpImg.src = currentImg;
}
```

```html
<input type = "file" accept = "image/*" onchange = "handleUploadedFile(event)">
```

De hecho te tengo buenas noticias, resulta y pasa que puedes transmutar cualquier imagen que sea soportada por los navegadores a el formato **webp** puesto que se sabe que la mayoria de los navegadores soportan el formato de imagen **webp**, ese ejemplo de arriba demuestra que si es posible transmutar una imagen de algun formato soportado por el navegador a **webp** sin necesidad de enviarlo al servidor!, es realmente genial!.

Sin embargo como siempre hay malas noticias...

Resulta que el método `canvas.toDataURL` que es el que hace la magia aquí, solo soporta como output de imagen en la mayoria de navegadores los tipos `image/jpeg` e `image/png` hasta donde se **no soportan ningun otra extensión**, excepto el navegador **google chrome** el cuál **SI** soporta la extensión **webp** como output de **canvas.toDataURL**.

Por lo cuál se hace dependiente que el usuario si o si este usando el navegador **Google Chrome** para usar esta opción, otros navegadores como `firefox` u `opera` no soportan la extensión de archivo **webp** para el caso del metodo `canvas.toDataURL` pero si soportan la visualización y carga de estas.

Por lo que esta solución funcionará solo para aquellos usuarios que utilicen el navegador **Google Chrome** en cualquier otro navegador el formato por defecto de output es `image/png`.

Ahora bien, voy a explicar solo aquellas cosas que pueden resultarte nuevas, como por ejemplo:

- **URL.createObjectURL**: Crea un enlace único de un recurso en base a un tipo `Blob` o un tipo `File` leyendo su data, este link **NO** es publico, y solo es usable en la misma ventana del navegador (acceso remoto imposible y prohibido).
- **URL.revokeObjectURL**: Destruye los datos cargados en la `URL` para liberar el espació que estaba usando la `URL`, es bueno usarlo cuando este seguro de que ya no requieres ese recurso.
- **new Image()**: Podemos construir imagenes desde javascript, pero no te equivoques, como parametros no recibe la imagen, si no las dimensiones de la imagen, es por ello que mas adelante asignamos un `src` como si se tratase de un elemento `img` obtenido desde `JS`.
- **ctx.drawImage**: Asumo que te es familiar este metodo, sin embargo lo no familiar puede ser el contexto en el que es usado, verás usamos este metodo para que al redimensionar el `canvas` podamos pintar la imagen extraida desde el `input file`, la manera de hacerlo es primero pintando la imagen en el `canvas` y luego extrayendo sus pixeles, es por eso que primero necesitamos dibujarla en el `canvas` (aunque el canvas no sea tecnicamente visible se puede).
- **canvas.toDataURL**: Este método se usa para extraer todos los pixeles del area del canvas y convertirlos a una imagen, como parametros recibe el **tipo de imagen** de output y la **calidad** con la que se verá la imagen output, donde `0.1` es lo minimo y `1.0` es lo maximo, por default si omitimos este parametro el valor por defecto es `0.92`.

Bien, ahora ya sabemos que si es posible hacer lo mismo sin siquiera enviar la imagen al servidor para convertirla a **webp** pero bajo una muy mala condición:

**Solo servirá en Google Chrome.**

Aunque si aún así deseas usar este método, entonces seguro te preguntaras...

**¿Y como rayos hago para pasar un string en base64 a una imagen descargable?**

La respuesta es sencilla...

Verás, el formato que nos devuelve `canvas.toDataURL` no es directamente `base64` si no una `URI` en formato `base64`, el cuál es legible directamente por una etiqueta `img` siempre y cuando tenga el formato adecuado, así que lo único que debes hacer para que la imagen sea descargable es, a esta nueva data obtenida como `base64` cargarla en un elemento `img`, y una vez cargada la data puedes setear el atributo `download` en ella para que sea descargable al darle click, donde tu nuevo string en `base64` se verá algo parecido a esto:

```
data:image/webp;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUA
```

Y muchos mas caracteres, es justo esta parte:

```
data:image/webp;base64,
```

Lo que le indica al navegador el tipo de dato que debe intentar cargar y reproducir, lo que hace la magia que permite que nosotros veamos una imagen tal cuál por medio de un string en `base64`, que a fin de cuentas es simplemente una codificación diferente que contiene la data de la imagen.

Resumiendo esto en un ejemplo, despues de esta parte de aquí:

```
convertedImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 1.0);
```

puedes usar `convertedImg` como `src` de la imagen directamente, quedando así:

```
convertedImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/webp", 1.0);
const imgToDownload = new Image(canvas.width, canvas.height);

imgToDownload.onload = ()=>{
   imgToDownload.download = "";
   document.body.appendChild(imgToDownload);
}

imgToDownload.src = convertedImg;
```

De esta manera podrás descargar la imagen en su nuevo formato **webp** sin embargo si por alguna razón no te lo permite o simplemente no ocurre nada, entonces deberás usar un elemento `a` para encerrar a tu `img` de la siguiente forma:

[HTML  download Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

En caso de querer una solución que funcione en cualquier navegador web, me temo que por el momento hasta donde se en javascript no hay otra manera de transmutar imagenes directamente.

Para esto se requiere de un lenguaje del lado del servidor, el cuál tienes, por ejemplo `PHP` o `nodejs` cualquiera de tu preferencia, por el cuál puedes enviar la data de una imagen y convertirla a otra usando ciertas herramientas de la shell (se pueden ejecutar comandos de la shell desde php o nodejs).

Yo por ejemplo usaba una herramienta de la `shell` de `linux` en `nodejs` para obtener un frame de un video con el formato que desee de imagen usando `ffmpeg`, luego simplemente respondia al cliente con la data traida por el servidor y la usaba, sin embgaro `ffmpeg` es mas bien especializado en `videos` y `audio` no se si sea la mejor opción para imagenes, puesto que nunca he intentado transmutar el formato de una imagen a otra usando `ffmpeg`.

Una ultima cosa, y es que si lo que quieres es **enviar la imagen ya transmutada** por medio del formulario, resulta y pasa que existe una limitación, y es que el objeto `FileList` que devuelve `ev.currentTarget.files` es de solo lectura, por lo cuál, si deseas añadir esta nueva imagen **no podras hacerlo de ninguna manera**.

A menos claro que uses `ajax` para enviar la imagen...

No voy a ondar mucho en `ajax`, puesto que eso se presta para otra pregunta, sin embargo, lo correcto a la hora de enviar una imagen al servidor, no sería enviar la imagen como un **string en base64** directamente, que es justo lo que obtendrías al usar el metodo `canvas.toDataURL`, así que voy a ayudarte en una cosa mas para poder pasar de un **string en base64** a un tipo `Blob`, y luego de eso a un tipo `File` el cuál sería el formato ideal que deberías enviar por medio de `ajax`.

Para ello te redirijo a la siguiente pregunta en la que di una propuesta de solución:

[Error 413 al intentar subir fotografia desde celular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359674/error-413-al-intentar-subir-fotografia-desde-celular/359686#359686)

Puede que por el titulo te suene a que no tiene nada que ver, sin embargo en mi respuesta explico las dos cosas relevantes:

como pasar de `base64` a `Blob` y luego de un tipo `Blob` a un tipo `File`.

El porque de no usar simplemente el `Blob` o el `base64` para enviarlo al servidor es por 2 razones:

- **base64** es una codificación de caracteres que es mas pesada que el formato original del archivo, pero es segura, al enviar datos en `base64` puede ocurrir una perdida si la info es muy grande, ademas si usas `PHP` del lado del servidor un `base64` no será detectado como recurso en la variable `$_FILES` de `PHP`, la cuál brinda información muy útil.
- **Blob** es un tipo de formato usado para archivos de gran tamaño, difiere del formato en `base64` puesto que se acerca mas al formato binario, ademas es mas ligero, pero para poder ser enviado se requieren cabeceras especiales y pueden corromperse los datos al ser enviados como un `Blob` plano, ademas la carga de envio será menos optima e inestable, ademas de no almacenarse en la variable `$_FILES` de `PHP` al ser enviada, haciendo que información útil no pueda ser recolectada directamente.
- **File** es el formato contenedor de cualquier recurso cargado en un input tipo `file` o generado mediante un `Blob` (se pueden construir `Blobs` y a la vez tambien se pueden construir `Files`), el tipo `File` usa `Blobs` para crear un archivo con cierta información útil la cuál puede ser enviada directamente a los servidores, entre ellos `PHP` para posteriormente ser recolectada en la variable `$_FILES` de `PHP` así como su data, ademas permite escribir directamente el recurso en vez de tener que transformarlo para escribirlo. Es mas estable y rapido para el transporte que un `Blob` plano.

Comment: nota: ffmpeg tambien existe en windows, solo que la instalación es diferente, en linux puedes instalarlo desde la shell, en windows debe descargarse para simplemente ejecutarse desde la shell una vez lo tienes.

Comment: Nota importante 2: si intentas usar esto en un navegador diferente a chrome y luego reemplazar ya sea image/png o image/jpeg como truco para obtener un string con tipo image/webp como resultado la imagen estará corrupta (no funciona así).

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ocuparé las ideas que me ha dado! Realmente muchas gracias